# How do I get the enemy character to stop circling the player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now, and I'm very sure it has something to do with my code. What I want the enemy monster to do is to stop moving forward when the player right next to it and run the attack animation. What it actually does is run the attack animation while orbiting around the player like a planet, and you can't really outrun it.

I'm using Unity3d as the engine and my code is written in C#. It's very simple so I'm worried I'm missing something important.

```
public class enemyAITest : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Transform player;      // target
    public float playerDistance;  // determines how far from target before action takes place
    public float rotationDamping; // determines how quickly rotation occurs
    public float chaseSpeed;      // determines how quickly to pursue target
    public float wanderSpeed;     // determines how quickly to move around map
    public float maxDist;

    static Animator anim;
    Vector3 wayPoint;


    void Awake()
    {
       anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    } 

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        transform.position += transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * wanderSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        playerDistance = Vector3.Distance(player.position, transform.position);

            while ((transform.position - wayPoint).magnitude < 3)
                Wander();

            if (playerDistance < 20f)
            {
               LookAtPlayer();
               wanderSpeed = 0;
               anim.SetBool("isIdle", true);
            }

            if (playerDistance < 10f)
            {
               Chase();
               anim.SetBool("isIdle", false);
               anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
               anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);                           
            }

            if(playerDistance < 1f)
            {
                wanderSpeed = 0;
                anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
                anim.SetBool("isAttacking", true);
            }
       else anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
    }

    void LookAtPlayer()
    {
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(player.position - transform.position);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationDamping);
        wanderSpeed = 0;
    }

    void Chase()
    {
        Vector3 direction = player.position - transform.position;
        direction.y = 0;
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * chaseSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

       void Wander()
    {
        Vector3 MonsterPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(transform.position.x - maxDist, transform.position.x + maxDist), 1, Random.Range(transform.position.z - maxDist, transform.position.z + maxDist));
        wayPoint.y = 1;
        transform.LookAt(wayPoint);
        //Debug.Log(wayPoint + " and " + (transform.position - wayPoint).magnitude);
    }
}
```

Any advice will help (Please forgive the strange formatting, I was having trouble with keeping the entire Wander method and the on Awake line in the code block).

Comment: Remarkably that stopped it from circling, but it still continues to move forward. When I stopped it so it could run its idle animation, I was able to use wanderSpeed = 0, but that doesn't seem to work for attacking. Is there a better way to stop it? EDIT: I figured it out, needed to use chaseSpeed instead of wanderSpeed. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Please don't add further informations on the questions with comments. [Edit] your question instead.